# ADF copy activity is failing while converting from string to Decimal

Tags: type-conversion, azure-data-factory

I have a copy activity in Azure Data Factory that takes CSV file as source and SQL table as destination.

Source data type is 'string' and destination is 'Decimal'

Let's take an example of source value ,

**100612324864664000.00**

This is the error message I am getting ,

**Message=Column 'xyz' contains an invalid value '1.0061232486466467E+17'.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ServiceLibrary,''Type=System.ArgumentException,Message=Input string was 
not in a correct format.Couldn't store <1.0061232486466467E+17> in xyz Column. Expected type is Decimal.**

Answer (score 1):

I tested your description and it works for me.

Source dataset:

[image]

Sink dataset:

[image]

Pipeline mapping:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have the same problem. You need to use 'format' in your "toDecimal" method. eg:

```
toDecimal("123.45",10,4,'#.##')
```